# Spark Exception Complex types not supported while loading parquet

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to load Parquet File in Spark as dataframe-

```
val df= spark.read.parquet(path)
```

I am getting -

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 12, 10.250.2.32): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Complex types not supported.
```

While going through the code, I realized there is a check in spark VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java (initializeInternal)-

```
Type t = requestedSchema.getFields().get(i);
  if (!t.isPrimitive() || t.isRepetition(Type.Repetition.REPEATED)) {
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Complex types not supported.");
}
```

So I think its failing on isRepetition method.
Can anybody suggest me the way to solve the issue ?

My Parquet Data is like -

```
Key1 = value1
Key2 = value1
Key3 = value1
Key4:
.list:
..element:
...key5:
....list:
.....element:
......certificateSerialNumber = dfsdfdsf45345
......issuerName = CN=Microsoft Windows Verification PCA, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
......subjectName = CN=Microsoft Windows, OU=MOPR, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
......thumbprintAlgorithm = Sha1
......thumbprintContent = sfdasf42dsfsdfsdfsd
......validFrom = 2009-12-07 21:57:44.000000
......validTo = 2011-03-07 21:57:44.000000
....list:
.....element:
......certificateSerialNumber = dsafdsafsdf435345
......issuerName = CN=Microsoft Root Certificate Authority, DC=microsoft, DC=com
......subjectName = CN=Microsoft Windows Verification PCA, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
......thumbprintAlgorithm = Sha1
......thumbprintContent = sdfsdfdsf43543
......validFrom = 2005-09-15 21:55:41.000000
......validTo = 2016-03-15 22:05:41.000000
```

> And I suspect the key4 may be raising the issue because of nested
>   tree. The input data is of Json type, so may be parquet doesn't
>   understand that complex levels as Json

I found a bug in Spark 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13744

but it states Hive Complex Type Issue. Not Sure, this will fix the issue with parquet or not?

**Update 1**
Further exploring the parquet and I concluded following -

I have 5 parquet file created while spark.write
Among that 2 parquet file is empty so the schema for a column which was supposed to be ArrayType is coming as String type and when I am trying to read it as whole, I saw the above exception

Comment: Which tool was used to create that Parquet file, in the first place?

Comment: using Spark dataframe write spark.write.parquet command

Answer (score 1):

**Take 1**
[SPARK-12854 Vectorize Parquet reader](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12854) indicates that *"ColumnarBatch supports structs and arrays"* (cf. [GitHub pull request 10820](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10820)) starting with Spark 2.0.0

And [SPARK-13518 Enable vectorized parquet reader by default](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13518), also starting with Spark 2.0.0, deals with property `spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader` (cf. [GitHub commit e809074](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/e8090740fe374977fd1ea2ed5e7c369827a46e7b))

My 2 cents: disable that "VectorizedReader" optimization and see what happens.

**Take 2**
Since the problem has been narrowed down to some empty files that do not display the same schema as "real" files, my 3 cents: experiment with `spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema` to see if the schema from real files takes precedence after [merging](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging).

Other than that, you might try to eradicate the empty files at write time, with some kind of re-partitioning e.g. `coalesce(1)` *(OK, 1 is a bit caricatural, but you see the point)*.

Comment: Doing that I am getting org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file {hdfs parquet file location) , now the error is precise